# chokidar works in VS code debugger, but not able to load when Electron app is built

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using chokidar to monitor file changes in directory. The following works if the app is started in VS code debugger.

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
```

But, after building the app, and start the app by clicking the app icon, it has following error in a popup dialog

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'chokidar'
```

This is Electron and Electron-builder version:

```
electron-builder  version=22.13.1 os=20.2.0
writing effective config  file=dist/builder-effective-config.yaml
packaging       platform=darwin arch=x64 electron=11.5.0 appOutDir=dist/mac
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Is `chokidar` a dependency or a dev-dependency in your `package.json` file?

Comment: @midnight-coding. Added     "chokidar": "^3.2.2", to package.json dependency section, and worked. Why this package needs to be manually added to package.json?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message `Cannot find module 'chokidar'` indicates Node cannot find the `chokidar` package within your
applications `node_modules` folder.

As your Electron application needs this package to run after it has been built, it needs to be added to
the `dependencies` section of your `package.json` file.

> If a package is only required for development purposes (IE: During development of your Electron application), then
> it should be added to the `devDependencies` section of your `package.json` file.
>
> If a package is installed globally then it will not be available to users of your application should they not have it
> installed globally themselves. Therefore, it is good practice to always have required packages installed with your application (as
> dependencies) and not rely on your user needing to install these packages themselves for your application to work.

You can add `chokidar` to your project by running `npm install chokidar` at a command prompt (at the root of your
project).

If you require a specific version of `chokidar`, it can be specified during the installation
EG: `npm install chokidar@3.2.2`

If you want `chokidar` to update each and every time you update, use `npm install chokidar@^3.0.0`

> PS: Keeping the major version number of the package (in this case `3`) fixed, allows updates to the minor version and
> patch numbers. Doing it this way **should not** break your application when packages are updated.

See [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install)
and [npm-update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-update) for more information.

Comment: @midnight-coding.Thank you. After specifying chokidar in package.json, built Electron app worked for Mac. But it does not work for built Window app. The problem is that Windows app does not even load. I am watching file add/delete of a directory.  This is the code: const watcherAppDir = chokidar.watch(this.appDir, {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true}); 'this.appDir' is a full path directory. The reason that I know chokidar causes the problem is that the built window app works after removing chokidar related code.

Comment: Is `this.appDir` an OS dependant or independent path? How is it set? Is it hard coded into your Electron application or does the user have the ability to change / update it? Additionally, is it within the root directory of your Electron application or outside of it like the users `home`, `documents` or `downloads` folders? The answers to these questions will indicate what the problem may be and how to fix the issue between operating systems. You mentioned that `this.appDir` is a full path directory. If it is a hard coded absolute (vs relative) path then this will be the cause of the issue.

Comment: this.appDir is obtained through const dialog = electron.dialog.  let selDirObj = dialog.showOpenDialog(), let selDir = selDirObj.filePaths[0]. It's platform independent, and is used in Windows to retrieve child files without problem. this.appDir is full path and is not relative to app. this.appDir seems having problem (app not load)on Windows (mac ok) when used  "chodidar". Handler is created when app is started: const watcherAppDir = chokidar.watch(this.appDir, {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});watcherAppDir.on('add'...). After removing handler, Windows app is able to load.

Comment: Tried const watcherAppDir = chokidar.watch(this.appDir, {persistent: true}); on Windows as well. It also fails.

Comment: Is there a main process console.log error when initialising `chokidar.watch()` on Microsoft Windows? Additionally, following initialisation, can you add the lines `watcherAppDir.on('ready', () => { console.log('Chokidar ready for changes'); });`, `console.log('Watching ' + watcherAppDir.getWatched());`  and `watcherAppDir.on('error', (error) => { console.log('Error: ' + error); });` Compare the outputs between MacOS and Windows and note back in the comments here. See [Chokidar on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) for more information.

Comment: I changed the timing of chokidar.watch() to be created, after ipcRenderer is created. The reason I have to change is to pass log info to renderer process. Now, all works. Thanks.